# htacess internal rewrite rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have links on wp localhost xampp setup pages as `http://localhost/mysite/portal/jxcc`  . the `jxcc` is different for different urls . I am trying to tell server to process them internally as `http://localhost/mysite/portal/go.php?id=jxcc` but nothing works . When i open the link in addressbar `http://localhost/mysite/portal/jxcc` , it says error 403 access forbidden. If i directly copy paste it in format `http://localhost/mysite/portal/go.php?id=jxcc` then it opens & processes the php output on page  . I tried different tutorials and looking for answers on Stack Overflow, but whatever I do to the url doesnt get processed internally correctly by server . Some things i  tried as below. ? I want the visitor to keep seeing `http://localhost/mysite/portal/jxcc` but the server should *internally* process it as `http://localhost/mysite/portal/go.php?id=jxcc` . Note the visitor will/should never be able to see `go.php?id=` . What should i do

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ portal/go.php?id=$1
```

***NEW EDIT*** :

Contents of .htaccess file  :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ portal/go.php?id=$1
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Location of .htaccess file : `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\.htaccess`

Comment: Where abouts is the `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? Is `.htaccess` enabled for this directory in the server config? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: It’s weird that you should get a 403, I’d have expected a 500, caused by the internal redirect limit getting exceeded. `portal/(.*)` will match on `portal/go.php` in the next round again (rewriting configured in .htaccess “loops”, until no more rules apply.) If you are on Apache 2.4, try the [`[END]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) to prevent all further processing; otherwise, you might need to be more specific with your pattern, or exclude request for `portal/go.php` using an additional RewriteCond.

Comment: @MrWhite, yes there are other security directives in the wp htaccess, also its enabled ..its wp site..mod_rewrite also on..tested all these at first before starting with modifications . What could be wrong with the current scenario ?

Comment: @04FS , its 403 . i tried it this way `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ portal/go.php?id=$1 [END]`  this one gives 403 error . Also a new thing i notice is if i visit directly `http://localhost/mysite/portal/go.php?id=jxcc` i get blank page while before applying htaccess rule, page  opened normally & showed output of .php file . `portal` folder just has `go.php` which executes a code based on parameter of `id` while links on  wp pages - `http://localhost/mysite/portal/jxcc` where `jxcc` will be different for different links & has numbers,alphabets,special characters like `+ = /` .

Comment: Please edit your question to include your full `.htaccess` file. It sounds like you have the directives in the wrong order and are probably conflicting with your existing directives (which is perhaps what's preventing a rewrite loop (or at least an undesirable 2nd rewrite) that @04FS mentioned above). And to confirm, is your `.htaccess` file in the `/mysite` subdirectory?